# Why index without .php is directing to site homepage without AJAX functionality?

Tags: php

I have put a project on a live server resides at my home has Ubuntu Server 12.04.1 LTS. I have in the project folder the directories as below:

- index.php
- js_folder
- classes_folder
- images_folder

When I go to the domain like: http://mydomain.com/index, it directs me to the website homepage (but with missing AJAX call to load) instead of giving me error 404 - page not found. When I go to http://mydomain.com/WERQ, I get page not found.

But when I go to the domain like: http://mydomain.com/index.php, the website completely works fine!

I tried on my windows WAMP server, but this doesn't happen there!

Could you please advise me how to check this problem? It is strange and I don't have any directory named "index", I just have index.php.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a page named index.html at the root?

Comment: What happens when you try http://mydomain.com

Comment: Solved as per Webrain comment! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably configured the [MultiviewsMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#MultiviewsMatch) directive for this directory, that's why the Apache web server delivers the index.php file when you enter /index

Comment: Thank you very much webrain! Appreciate your help! :) It works! To explain it to others: I removed "MultiViews" from <Directory /var/www/mydomain>, it became like below:

<Directory /var/www/mydomain>
    Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks 
</Directory>